# How to parse json in parquet file using apache/arrow

Tags: json, go, parquet, apache-arrow

I am using [Apache arrow for Go](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/go) to read parquet files. The schema of my parquet file is:

```
time_stamp: int64
file_name:  byte_array
offset:     int32
meta_data:  byte_array
```

That information is printed by `fmt.Println(rdr.MetaData().Schema)`. Although it says column `metadata` is a byte array, it's actually a json string like following:

```
{
    "dataType": "left", 
    "features": [
        {
            "feature_name": "dHash", 
            "feature_val": "0000011000000111000001110010011100011111000101110000010100000101"
        }
    ], 
    "pipelineVersion": "0.0"
}
```

So how can I parse this information into a struct? I have found following methods to read a parquet file, but there seems to be no parameter for schema:

```
mem := memory.NewCheckedAllocator(memory.DefaultAllocator)
filename := "parquet file path"

rdr, _ := file.OpenParquetFile(filename, false, file.WithReadProps(parquet.NewReaderProperties(mem)))
arrowRdr, _ := pqarrow.NewFileReader(rdr, pqarrow.ArrowReadProperties{}, mem)
tbl, _ := arrowRdr.ReadTable(context.Background())
defer tbl.Release()

chunk0 := tbl.Column(0).Data().Chunk(0)
fmt.Println(chunk0)
```

And there is no example in [official doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/arrow/go/v9/parquet) at all.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> That information is printed by fmt.Println(rdr.MetaData().Schema). Although it says column metadata is a byte array, it's actually a json string like following:

If the json payloads has been stored as a json byte array/string in parquet, then you'll have to parse it and convert it to a struct manually. There are some [helper functions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/json.html) that can handle json data, but it doesn't look like they are exposed in go.

If you want parquet to handle it automatically as a struct, you'd have to store it as a struct when writing the file.